# animateLayoutChanges problems with ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to use an ActivityList but it does not work well.
In fact, I cannot select any item of the list; I can do that only after selecting an option such as "add item" from the menu. Why ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a statement, not a question. 

Comment: Self-answering is ok but still format your posts as questions and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right...  can I still correct the question and insert the answer just below ?

Comment: done, now it should be ok

Answer (score 5):

I have just found out this bug:
using the option `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the layout of the ListView prevents you from selecting any item of the ListView; you can do that, only after doing something like adding a new item and returning to the ListView. I have experienced this bug using the SimpleCursorAdapter up-to-date and the one that comes with v4 support library.

Hope it helps (I have wasted a lot of time !)